# Queryset Django Show Object one time

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

I have a question about makeing queries with django.
I am filtering my query, 
but in few of them they have more then one information.

For example

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher_id = ....
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)

class Language(models.Model):
    language_id = ....
    language = ....
```

Now I got a few Objects from Teacher and Language in my Database

Teacher 1 has got many information and he can speak 3 language.
Is there this ForeignKey ok, or should i rather use ManyToManyField?
(Thats not the final question)

i now can search for some teacher and i have a form, where i can put some information that is important for me.

Something like, i am searching for a teacher, who can speck english and french, for example.

I have this in my View

```
query = Teacher.object.all()
q = Q(is_active=True)

    language = request.POST.getlist('language', [x.language_id for x in Language.objects.all()])
    if language:
       q &=Q(language__in=language)
```

Now im using the Paginator,

```
paginator = Paginator(query.filter(q), items_per_page)
```

Now I got the problem right here,

my filter shows now all Teacher with the Language French and English but now 2 times.

I want to show all objects just one time..

What I have do to?

I Hope you understand, what i am meaning.

Comment: I dont understand your code as I dont know your POSTed data, but what about using .distinct() on your query??

Comment: if a Teacher can speak more than one Language then you need a ManyToManyField

Comment: I assume you are seeing the same teacher twice because you have made two `Teacher` records for the same teacher, one for French language and one for English language... using a ManyToMany would fix this, as you'd only have a single `Teacher` record for each teacher

Comment: The problem was not the ManyToManyField it works also great with the forgeinkey.using .distinct() made my day. thx for answearing

Comment: Like Anentropic said, if the teacher can speak more than 1 language, you are going to need m2m.